# Reaching fixed point of "type"

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

Calling `type(x)` on an object `x` returns the type of that object. Calling `type(type(...type(x)...))` always eventually yields `type` itself, with `type(type) = type` being a fixed point. The most complex example I could come up with was

```py
class Meta(type):
    pass

class C(metaclass=Meta):
    pass

x = C()
```

which requires three calls to type (`type(type(type(x)))`) to evaluate to `type`.

Is it true for any expression in Python, that at most three calls to `type` are needed to reach the fixed point? If not, is there a finite limit (just larger than three) or can the required stack of `type` calls grow indefinitely?

Comment: Note that in your example, ``isinstance(Meta, type)``, or in other words ``type(C) <: type``. Requiring the extra ``type`` layer is merely from ignoring subtyping. However, ``type(type) == type`` is a base case, from which arbitrary many further levels can be derived.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The required stack of `type` calls can grow indefinitely.

Here is an example:

```
>>> class Meta(type):
...     pass
... 
>>> class C(type, metaclass=Meta):
...     pass
... 
>>> class D(type, metaclass=C):
...     pass
... 
>>> class E(type, metaclass=D):
...     pass
... 
>>> class F(type, metaclass=E):
...     pass
... 
>>> f = F("1",(),{});
>>> type(f)
<class '__main__.F'>
>>> type(type(f))
<class '__main__.E'>
>>> type(type(type(f)))
<class '__main__.D'>
>>> type(type(type(type(f))))
<class '__main__.C'>
>>> type(type(type(type(type(f)))))
<class '__main__.Meta'>
>>> type(type(type(type(type(type(f))))))
<class 'type'>
>>> type(type(type(type(type(type(type(f)))))))
<class 'type'>
>>>
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but I think all objects are stored in heap, while the pointer to object itself is stored in stack

Comment: heap is used when stack overflows, for local variables which get changed a lot like i in loops; stack is used for global data and function returns, a typical segmentation fault in c is a overflow in stack or accessing non-permissable locations

Answer (score 1):

The case `type(type) == type` is merely the base case of instantiatable types. Just as the first layer of types can be created from `type`, further layers can be constructed. There is no fixed limit.

```py
def descend(base=type):
    while True:
        class base(base, metaclass=base):
            pass
        yield base

def type_depth(tp):
    depth = 0
    while type(tp) != type:
          depth += 1
          tp = type(tp)
    return depth

for tp in descend():
    print(tp, type_depth(tp))
```

Practically, there is a limit for the *usefulness* of meta-layers: Most classes are direct instances of `type` itself or one of its subtypes.